# A folder of Xml files to Csv

Tags: python, pandas, elementtree

The code bellow takes an XML files and parses it to CSV file

```
import pandas as pd


def phones_to_df(fname):
    tree = cET.parse(fname)
    pd.DataFrame([{**{el.tag: el.text for el in list(phone)},
                   **{f'nuk_{k}': v for k, v in phone.find('nuk').items()}}
                  for phone in tree.iterfind('Phones')]).to_csv('export.csv', index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    phones_to_df(fname="test.xml")
```

The xml file is as follows

```
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Phones>
    <Date />
    <Prog />
    <Box />
    <Feature />
    <WIN>MAFWDS</WIN>
    <Set>234234</Set>
    <Pr>23423</Pr>
    <Number>afasfhrtv</Number>
    <Simple>dfasd</Simple>
    <Nr />
    <gt>6070106091</gt>
    <Reno>1233</Reno>
    <QW>3234</QW>
    <ER />
    <VR />
    <Use />
    <Dar>sdfsd</Dar>
    <age />
    <name1>sdfsfdfs</name1>
    <Sys>Itone</Sys>
    <aac>2014</aac>
    <time>02:00</time>
    <nuk name="This is some text" text_g="asadsdas" text_h="2">fsdfsfd3432fdf</nuk>
  </Phones>

</Data>
```

The code goes through the elements of **Phones** and prints them into a csv file that is called *test.xml*

Now, I'm trying to modify the code so instead of reading just one xml file, it goes to a folder and iterates through all the xml files in there and parses them into one single Csv file.

I know I have to import

```
from pathlib import Path
```

The path to the folder where all the xml files are

```
xmls = [f for f in Path('C:/Users/Desktop/Original/test').glob('*.xml')]
```

I'm struggling on how to implement it into the code and make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your function for each filename, so something like:

```
pd.concat([phones_to_df(xml) for xml in xmls])
```

Calling the function with each xml-filename will result in a list of dataframes, and that will be concatenated with [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), leaving you with a dataframe with all results. You can then export this with the [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) function.

In total it would be something like this:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as cET
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

def phones_to_df(fname):
    tree = cET.parse(fname)
    return pd.DataFrame([{**{el.tag: el.text for el in list(phone)},
                          **{f'nuk_{k}': v for k, v in phone.find('nuk').items()}}
                  for phone in tree.iterfind('Phones')])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xmls = [f for f in Path('C:/Users/Desktop/Original/test').glob('*.xml')] 
    df = pd.concat([phones_to_df(xml) for xml in xmls])
    df.to_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/Original/all.csv")
```

Comment: thank you maybe I'm asking for too much but can you just show me the entire code on how would u implement this to my already existing code

Comment: Here is is how I tried it but its not working https://controlc.com/a2fbacbf

Comment: did you maybe had the chance to look at the link I send on the comment above, I still couldn't make it work

Comment: @ebe do you get an error message? The fourth line should be removed anyway, because nothing is declared yet (so remove the first line after the imports, `pd.concat([phones_to_df(xml) for xml in xmls])
`)

Comment: I tried without that line and I get a ValueErorr: All objects pessed were none.  What I dont understand is why in the for loop we save to a csv file nd then again df.to_csv

Comment: Ahh, check. In the function, remove the `.to_csv()` part and do a `return` of the created df. So the final line of the function becomes `return pd.DataFrame([ _stuff_ ])`

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the full code? Because no the last line I changed from df.to_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/Original/all.csv") to return  pd.Datafame("C:/Users/Desktop/Original/all.csv") and I'm getting return outside function

Comment: @ebe see answer

Comment: Can you please help me remove first column that is only showing zero for some reason. Would really appreciate it